# Another option of popup selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which has a disabled field for company name. It has a button, on clicking it, a search window opens up and there we can search the company name and then submit. On Submit,the disabled field is filled in the parent window. But I am not happy with the pop-up window. I need other option using where we can search in the same window. Any suggestions?

Comment: i guess someone will ask you to edit it

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion can be that there can be a `Select2` like search as you type.

Btw, https://ux.stackexchange.com/ is appropriate site for such questions.